# Close Popup window in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, salesforce1-platform

I need to close a popup window in Salesforce1.

When it opens in a normal browser, the popup is closed using `Window.close()`

But in case of Salesforce1(App Browser), the `Window.close()` does not work. Is there any workaround to close the popup?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say Salesforce1, are you trying this on a real device or in emulated mode on a browser (using the `/one/one.app` suffix)? If there are any errors, it should show up in the console log.

Else, you should try the following

```
window.top.close();
```

or

```
window.self.close();
```